# Haskell - Pattern matching in Case Of "Couldn't match expected type"

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, case-statement

I have a custom datatype similar to:

```
data Token = Number Int
           | Otherthings
```

I want to be able to use the "Number" in one way and other things in another. So I can successfully create a case statement like:

```
parse x = case x of
    Number y -> y
```

Which then successfully takes:

```
let x = Number 7 in parse x
```

And evaluates to 7. However, when I try to change the "parse" function to be:

```
parse [] = []
parse (x:xs) = case x of
    Number y -> y
```

I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `Int'
In the expression: y
In a case alternative: Number y -> y
In the expression: case x of { Number y -> y }
```

Why doesn't this work this way and what's the proper way to approach this problem? Thank you much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the types of the two parts of `parse`'s definition separately.

```
parse :: [a] -> [b] -- both the []'s are lists of some (possibly different) type
parse [] = []
```

and

```
parse :: [Token] -> Int -- y, the function's return value, is an Int.
parse (x:xs) = case x of
    Number y -> y
```

and you can see that while `a ~ Token` works just fine, `[b] ~ Int` doesn't work: an Int is not a list of something. (The error message is using `a0` where I'm using `b`.)

The way out of this is to think about what type you want `parse` to return, and make sure all the parts of its definition match it. I'm not sure exactly what you want `parse` to do, so I can't give a definite answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Your two definitions of `parse` have different types. `parse []` returns a list, whereas `parse (x:xs)` returns a naked number.

You could make it work, e.g., by returning the number in a singleton list

```
parse [] = []
parse (x:xs) = case x of
    Number y -> [y]
```

or by returning a number for the empty-list case

```
parse [] = 0
parse (x:xs) = case x of
    Number y -> y
```

or in a number of other ways, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: The problem with both of your approaches is that when `parse` is passed an `Otherthings` as the head of the list, you will get an exception.

Comment: @rtaboada: Yes, of course; it is not meant as a production-grade solution. :-) But the question is about the type error, which can be avoided in either way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your second `parse` function is returning a `List` when passed the empty list and it is trying to return a `Int` when passed a non-empty `List`. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

When you are using a case or pattern matching is good practice to write all the possible constructors. Think about what would happens in your `parse` function when someone call it with `[Otherthings, Number 3]` for example.

You should probably use `Maybe` instead and match all constructors of the `Data type`:

```
parse []     = Nothing
parse (x:xs) = case x of
    Number y    -> Just y
    Otherthings -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have

```
parse x = case x of
    Number y -> y
```

And you want to have parseList, it looks like:

```
parseList = map parse
```

or write it in more verbose way:

```
parseList [] = []
parseList (x:xs) = parse x : parseList xs
```

or

```
parseList [] = []
parseList (x:xs) = case x of
    Number y -> y : parseList xs
```

Maybe you forgot to parse rest elements, parsing only first one